# Makefile: macros with default parameters

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following Makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables

define foobar
echo "$(1)"
endef

.PHONY: all
all:
    $(foobar)
```

Is there a way to have macros with default parameters without producing undefined variable warnings?
I mean: sometimes I call "foobar" with a parameter, but sometimes not. In the latter case I'd like to have a default value for $(1).

Answer (score 7):

You can't set a default value in the macro but you can easily add one when the parameter is expanded:

```
1:=

define foobar
echo "$(if $1,$1,default)"
endef

all:
        $(foobar)
        $(call foobar,biz)

$ make
echo "default"
default
echo "biz"
biz
```

It's a bit annoying if you use the parameter lots of times because you have to use the `if` for each use.

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried, but it still raises an "undefined variable" warning. Try to add `MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables` to your snippet to verify. I also tried to find a clever way using the $(origin) function, but no success so far.

Comment: IMO "warn-undefined-variables" is of marginal utility at best.  However, you can avoid the warning by defining "1" as a global variable with an empty value, as I've edited above.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU make syntax is very limited; it's not a full blown programming language, so many things are missing, like default parameters in make macros.

But the shell is a programming language! Why not implement your requirements in the commands of a target? It may be possible to use something like this:

```
all:
    if test "$(SOMECONDITION)"; then \
         do_one_thing; \
    else \
         do_something_else; \
    fi
```

Comment: No, I need to abstract away this logic in a macro. It's used in many places. I simply need a macro that, without raising a warning, allows me to pass or not to pass a parameter. In the latter case a default value will be used.

Comment: @MarkTayo Can you make the macro ignore the arg when it is special, say, when it is 0, or a negative number, or an empty string? You should give us a concrete example for both uses.

Comment: I'm looking for a clean solution, without giving a special meaning to a particular arg. Only the mere absence of the arg should mean something (i.e. use the default value).

Comment: @MarkTayo You can't use a feature that's not implemented. If you insist on your definition of "clean" all you can do is ask MadScientist to implement it in GNU make for you -- or UTSL and hack away.

Comment: Just found the "clean" solution: `$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin 1)),default,$(1))`. It works. Now the best would be to have a "meta macro". Something that can be invoked from another macro like this: `$(call default,$(1),mydefaultvalue)`. It would be THE solution... General & clean...

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent solution for GNU make.  Not sure how portable it is.

Use a global variable that embodies the rather messy logic, using a naming convention to avoid conflicts:

```
# foo.mk
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables

foobar_p1_default = default parameter
foobar_p1 = $(if $(filter undefined,$(origin 1)),$(foobar_p1_default),$1)
define foobar
@echo $@: "$(foobar_p1)"
endef

.PHONY: all defaulted global local
all : defaulted global local
defaulted:
    $(foobar)

variable = global value
global local:
    $(call foobar,parameter was $(variable))

local: variable = target specific value
```

The results:

```
$ make -f foo.mk 
defaulted: default parameter
global: parameter was global value
local: parameter was target specific value
```